# Providing row data from a table in a notification

Tags: snmp, asn.1, mib

I have an SNMP MIB that provides tabular data. If possible, I'd like to add an SNMP notification that provides the same data as one row of the table.

As an example, I'll use the following table from the [NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB](http://www.net-snmp.org/docs/mibs/NET-SNMP-EXAMPLES-MIB.txt):

```
netSnmpHostsTable OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      SEQUENCE OF NetSnmpHostsEntry
    MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "An example table that implements a wrapper around the
        /etc/hosts file on a machine using the iterator helper API."
    ::= { netSnmpExampleTables 2 }

netSnmpHostsEntry OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      NetSnmpHostsEntry
    MAX-ACCESS  not-accessible
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "A host name mapped to an ip address"
    INDEX   { netSnmpHostName }
    ::= { netSnmpHostsTable 1 }

NetSnmpHostsEntry ::= SEQUENCE {
    netSnmpHostName         OCTET STRING,
    netSnmpHostAddressType  InetAddressType,
    netSnmpHostAddress      InetAddress,
    netSnmpHostStorage      StorageType,
    netSnmpHostRowStatus    RowStatus
}

--- Definitions of objects in the sequence omitted
```

Ideally, I'd like to add a new notification which provides the data associated with a single `NetSnmpHostsEntry`.

My initial attempt was this:

```
netSnmpHostsEntryNotification NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    OBJECTS     { netSnmpHostsEntry }
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "First crack at the notification."
    ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix 2 }
```

However, `smilint` reports these errors:

```
object `netSnmpHostsEntry' of notification `netSnmpHostsEntryNotification' must be a scalar or column
object `netSnmpHostsEntry' of notification `netSnmpHostsEntryNotification' must not be `not-accessible'
```

I roughly understand these errors. There are restrictions on what objects you can bind to a notification, and an object representing a row of a table is neither a scalar or a column and isn't valid.

I then tried changing that notification to this:

```
netSnmpHostWithEvent OBJECT-TYPE
    SYNTAX      NetSnmpHostsEntry
    MAX-ACCESS  read-only
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Host associated with the notification"
    ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix 3 }

netSnmpHostsEntryNotification NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    OBJECTS     { netSnmpHostWithEvent }
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Second crack at the notification."
    ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix 2 }
```

The linter gives a different error for this:

```
type `NetSnmpHostsEntry' of node `netSnmpHostWithEvent' does not resolve to a known base type
```

Again, I *think* this error makes sense. `NetSnmpHostsEntry` is declared as a `SEQUENCE`, not as a normal object. The items in that sequence are all defined as their own objects that link up to the `netSnmpHostsEntry` object, which itself links up to the `netSnmpHostsTable` object. In this example, the `NetSnmpHostsEntry` sequence is explicitly linked to the `netSnmpHostsTable` table, so the sequence isn't "usable" outside the context of the table.

This is mostly intuitive, and if I redefine the sequence in the notification, this gets through the linter without any errors<sup>1</sup>:

```
netSnmpHostsEntryNotification NOTIFICATION-TYPE
    OBJECTS {
        netSnmpHostName, netSnmpHostAddressType, netSnmpHostAddress,
        netSnmpHostStorage, netSnmpHostRowStatus
    }
    STATUS      current
    DESCRIPTION
        "Third crack at the notification."
    ::= { netSnmpExampleNotificationPrefix 2 }
```

I think this would work fine for the MIB I'm creating, but it does leave me with a few questions:

1. Is there any way to reuse a `SEQUENCE` in a notification?
2. Are there any issues with the final implementation of the notification that weren't caught by the linter?

<sup>1. I did need to change `MAX-ACCESS` of `netSnmpHostName` from `not-accessible` to `read-create` to make this work, but I don't think that's relevant to the general form of this question</sup>

Comment: I think the reason `netSnmpHostName` is `not-accessible` is that it's the `INDEX` of `netSnmpHostsEntry`, so if you send, say, `netSnmpHostAddressType` in the notification, it ought to encode `netSnmpHostName` in the OID, right?

Comment: @TallChuck You're right. I reread the section of RFC 2578 which covered the `INDEX` clause and it seems like `netSnmpNostName`  does need to be marked `not-accessible`. I'm not sure why that wasn't flagged by `smilint` when I changed it. I guess this might also answer my question -- I wouldn't even want to reuse my `SEQUENCE` in the notification if it were possible since that sequence includes the index.